# Shifting a data array elements in TensorFlow Variable in a neat way

Tags: arrays, variables, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have set of variables in TensorFlow, say `x1, x2,..., x9`
I am trying to shift the data of the variables in such a way that `x(i+1)` shifts to `x(i)` and eventually `x1` is lost and `x9` is the same. What I have tried is to create a dictionary of operations of shifting using `tf.assign()`, which works but it is slow.

A way I am thinking to do is to make a array of a `Variable` and then shift in the array itself using `tf.gather()` and `tf.scatter_update()` but it will again be a mess as lot of operations will be required.

I wanted to know if there is a good neat way of doing this in TensorFlow.
Another way I am thinking is to rename the variables which I believe is not possible.

Initial Code:

```
    #some tf.Variables are defined from n1 to n9 and assigned some values.
    k={}
    for i in range(1,10):             
        k[i]=tf.assign(n[i],n[i+1])   
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for j in range(1,10):
        sess.run(k[j])
```

Comment: Please post the code you have that you need help with.  It makes it far easier to help you with it...

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about rewriting your code as a sequence of slice operations? In general TensorFlow works best if you can express what you need to do as a series of operations on immutable objects, rather than changing variables. You'd do something like `tf.slice(n0, [1], [-1])` to pull out repeated sequences.